# KWin's wobbly windows do not work any more since I tried `i915_rc6_enable=1`

Tags: kwin

I recently tried to boot my Kubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Sandy Bridge Laptop with `i915.i915_enable_rc6=1`, `i915.i915_enable_fbc=1` and `i915.lvds_downclock=1`. I had some [issues with 3D performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210264/less-graphics-power-all-the-sudden-intel-hd-3000) where somebody suggested using those options.

Since the resolution was not set correctly, I just tried it again with `i915.i915_enable_rc6=1`, `i915.i915_enable_fbc=1`. Then I rebooted and did not set any options manually, so everything should be reset. But since then, some KWin effects, especially wobbly windows does not work any more.

I also tried to boot some older kernel, but that did not have any effect.

How can I get it back to work?

Answer (score -1):

kwin will disable desktop effects when it detects issues with drivers or hardware.

To re-enable them you can go to KDE's system-settings. Or you may be able to just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: Well, it does not re-enable wobbly windows.